# Retrieve tags from AWS account inside an organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, account

I am trying to use the AWS CLI to retrieve the list of tags and values attached to an AWS account inside our AWS Organisation without sucesss. Is there somebody that has done this before?

I tried the followwing: aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[].Id'); do   aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[].{ResourceARN:ResourceARN,Tags:Tags}' --output table --resource-type-filters AWS::AllSupported --region us-east-1 --account-id $account_id

but not luck

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the account tags for an organization, using the organizations API you will need at least the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ViewOrganizationAccountTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "organizations:DescribeAccount",
        "organizations:ListAccounts",
        "organizations:ListTagsForResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you got that in place, you can execute the following:

```
$ aws organizations list-accounts
{
    "Accounts": [
        {
            "Id": "<account_id>",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:organizations::<account_id>:account/<ou_id>/<id>",
            "Email": "email@domain.com",
            "Name": "<account_name>",
            "Status": "ACTIVE",
            "JoinedMethod": "CREATED",
            "JoinedTimestamp": "2020-11-20T17:40:23.085000+02:00"
        },
        {
            "Id": "...",
            "Arn": "...",
            "Email": "...",
            "Name": "...",
            "Status": "...",
            "JoinedMethod": "...",
            "JoinedTimestamp": "...."
        }
    ]
}
```

Then

```
$ aws organizations list-tags-for-resource --resource-id "target_account_id"
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "FOO1",
            "Value": "bar1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "FOO2",
            "Value": "bar2"
        }
    ]
}
```